# Pandas groupby transform('mean') skipna=False

Tags: python, pandas

I want to groupby to get the mean and assign it to all rows. Here is the code I am using. However, this is ignoring Nan i.e. skipna=True. I somehow want to pass the option skipna=False to get the expected output.

```
df["result"]=df.groupby("id")["cars"].transform('mean')
print (df)

Input dataframe

date id  cars
2012 1    4  
2013 1    6
2014 1    NaN    
2012 2    10 
2013 2    20 
2014 2    NaN

Current output:
   date  id  cars  result
0  2012   1   4.0     5.0
1  2013   1   6.0     5.0
2  2014   1   NaN     5.0
3  2012   2  10.0    15.0
4  2013   2  20.0    15.0
5  2014   2   NaN    15.0

Expected output:
   date  id  cars  result
0  2012   1   4.0     3.33
1  2013   1   6.0     3.33
2  2014   1   NaN     3.33
3  2012   2  10.0    10.0
4  2013   2  20.0    10.0
5  2014   2   NaN    10.0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
df['result'] = df.fillna(0).groupby("id")["cars"].transform('mean')
```

Comment: unfortunately the data I am dealing is weather data. It does address the original problem mentioned above however, when all the values are missing for a group it replaces it with 0. 0 is a valid temperature so I would like to have them as Nan.

Comment: But for your mean computation you want the nans to be interpreted as zeros ?

Comment: Yes it does solve the mean problem but I have a 3rd group with id 3 and cars value Nan. The expected result for that is Nan but I am getting 0.